# Could someone explain what is clock data recovery?

Tags: clock-recovery

I have read that clock data recovery is essential for decoding signals, for instance decoding output of rotary encoders

But I don't know how it helps to decode signals.

Any hint or reference would be welcome

Comment: Oversampling is meaning that you sample the signal with higher rate than it is expected to change. This way you get the same value several times when it is not expected to change, so every sample which is deviating from this value can be considered as a noise.

Comment: But surely the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling) can really explain it in much more comprehensive way

Comment: Why have you edited your question to something completely different? Clock recovery is a different concept. Like completely.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was confused, at the decoding circuit I was looking at was written oversampling clock. And I wrote clock oversampling, not just oversampling about which there is too much information on internet

Comment: The concepts are closely related in practice, with oversampling being a common way to obtain sufficient information for clock and data recovery.  But stack exchange sites are not for general explanations, but rather only for fully specific questions, which makes changing what exactly you are asking problematic.  Generally you should look elsewhere for general understanding, and here only for specific issues subsequent to that.

Comment: So what is the real question you are asking?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_recovery

Comment: @ChrisStratton Just now I read the very general question " what is a flip flop" 24 votes, 6 answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read that clock data recovery is essential for decoding signals, for instance decoding output of rotary encoders

This example is nonsense. Rotary encoders generate low-speed digital signals which can be decoded using a simple state machine. Clock recovery is neither necessary nor relevant to them.

Clock recovery is a technique that can be used to allow high-speed digital signals -- like USB, SATA, or PCI Express -- to be transmitted without an associated clock signal. Data is encoded using a scheme like [8b/10b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding) which guarantees a minimum density of transitions, and an edge detector and PLL are used to regenerate a data clock in the receiver.